# How can I clear parameter values in the WinForm ReportViewer control?

Tags: winforms, reportviewer

I am using the ReportViewer control to show my server report in my WinForm application. I set report parameters like this:

```
List<ReportParameter> parameterValues = new List<ReportParameter>();
...
parameterValues.Add(new ReportParameter("parameter name", "parameter value"));
...
myReportViewerControl.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameterValues);
```

I have a "CompanyName" parameter and I don't want to set this parameter. Maybe it is set for the first report load, but the second time I want to set it as unset. I want to clear the value.

I couldn't find any solution to clear parameter values.

How can I handle this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is too late with the answer, but to others who has the same issue...

To unset a parameter, assign an empty string value to it:

```
myReportViewerControl.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("parameter name", String.Empty));
```